# Rails 4 - Join with AND clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join

The query below gets me the user's next question based on the status of that question.  It gets all the questions for that specific section and then the scope does a `LEFT JOIN` on the statuses that belong to that user.

My question is, this doesn't seem like a very Railsy way to do it - is there a better way of filtering my table rather than this clumsy `AND` and `.to_s` business.  My issue is that obviously, if any user has answered that question, then the left join will fill up with that user's answer, whereas I require it to be null.

Essentially the query works but is ugly and I can't figure out if it's the most efficient way!

```
scope :next_for_user, lambda { |user|
    joins("LEFT JOIN user_question_statuses ON user_question_statuses.question_id = questions.id AND user_question_statuses.user_id = ", user.id.to_s).
    reorder("user_question_statuses.answered ASC NULLS FIRST").
    order("user_question_statuses.updated_at ASC NULLS FIRST").
    limit(1)
  }
```

**Edit:**

I realise this method is particularly vulnerable to SQL injection so I've replaced the main line in the query with:

```
joins(sanitize_sql_array(["LEFT JOIN user_question_statuses ON user_question_statuses.question_id = questions.id AND user_question_statuses.user_id = %d", user.id]))
```

which seems to work and forces the input to be an integer only.

**Edit 2:**

My other option is to use the `find_each` and then user `first_or_create` to create empty question statuses for that particular section of questions for the current user.  This could happen as and when they need them *before* looking for a question.  This would allow me to do a `RIGHT JOIN` from the questions on to those statuses, knowing they exist but if the first method is efficient and safe (and as Railsy as it can be), then there's not reason to change that.

**Edit 3:**

I have structured this query in this way because - from the `section` model that `has_many` `questions` - I want to find the next `question` that should be passed to a `user`.

To find this I need to join all of the `user_question_statuses` on to all of the `section` model's questions.  The only way this can be done is on `question.id`.  However, there are many `user_question_statuses` with that question id for different users. So when joining I need the `AND` clause to filter down the `user_question_statuses` to only ones from that `user` before the join happens.  A user hey obviously only have one status per `question`.

I use a `LEFT JOIN` so that if a status does not yet exist (they only get created after a user attempts a question for the first time) there are still statuses with `NULL`s everywhere so that they create a row from which to then move to the top (hence `NULLS FIRST`) and potentially server to the `user`.

This may all be extremely unclear!

Comment: @muistooshort - I've updated the answer.  Hopefully the explanation makes sense!

Answer (score -2):

What you did was skipping the ORM layer offered by Active Record and constructed the queries by yourself. Your feeling is correct that this approach as many limitations and is not a well fit to MVC model that rails is following. I would suggest a read through [Active Record Query Interface](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) to get concepts of doing it in the rails/oop way

Comment: I'm familiar with the query interface.  However, there is no method for using an `AND` clause on a `JOIN` though which require me to go outside of that.